# Caml String : How to search list by variable (string)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, caml-query

I have been trying to work on this for a few hours and a lot of googling.  New to caml queries I simply want to search my list where the variable matches in the column.

In sql I would write:

```
sql= SELECT COL1 FROM Table WHERE COL1 = '"+ VAR1 +"';
```

I am trying to retrieve the ID of the result.

```
function GetProdIDbyName(){
var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('MyListName');   
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();


camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Eq><FieldRef Name='Prod_x0020_Name' /><Value Type='Text'>" + ProdName + "</Value></Eq></Query></View>");   
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery)   
clientContext.load(collListItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(ProdIDSucceeded, ProdIDFailed);

}

function ProdIDSucceeded(sender, args) {

var listItemInfo = '';
var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
        '\nProd Value: ' + oListItem.get_item('Product_x0020_No');

}

alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function ProdIDFailed(sender, args) {

alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

But my results ignore the variable "ProdName" and returns all data in the column.  I read this is an issue with the caml string.

Some advice and guidance would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have added one line in your code as `context.load(collListItem, 'Include(---- Column name which you need ---)');`

Please check it.

```
function GetProdIDbyName(){
var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('MyListName');   
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();


camlQuery.set_viewXml("<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Text'>" + ProdName + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>");

this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
context.load(collListItem, 'Include(---- Column name which you need ---)');

clientContext.load(collListItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(ProdIDSucceeded, ProdIDFailed);

}

function ProdIDSucceeded(sender, args) {

var listItemInfo = '';
var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
        '\nProd Value: ' + oListItem.get_item('Product_x0020_No');

}
ProdID = oListItem.get_id();
ProdName = oListItem.get_item();

alert(RegID + " " +ProdName);
}

function ProdIDFailed(sender, args) {

alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: should it be :  clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(ID)');

Comment: i already mentioned that "Column name which you need". You will get it in output

Comment: Its not working it errors saying : The property or field 'Id' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

Comment: You need to load oListItem in ProdIDSucceeded method after var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

Like clientContext.load(oListItem);

Comment: This has confused me as in my first scenario the code works fine and gets the results  I need.  on debugging the error appers after the while ProdID = oListItem.get_id();
ProdName = oListItem.get_item();

Comment: The issue is the caml query not the code.

Comment: Found it. I was about to post the answer as you had two << braces in <<FieldRef. No problem. i have edited my answer now.

Comment: hehe I already found that error.  My results bring all the Product names and IDs so its ignoring the variable ProdName - do I need to use a filter?

Comment: camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><RowLimit>1</RowLimit><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Text'>" + ProdName + "</Value></Eq></View>"); This brings back the first record in the list

Comment: obviously it will get the first record because you have mentioned the RowLimit in query to 1.

Comment: no it returns the whole list so ive limited the row - it should only return one record not all of them.

Comment: If you found my answer helps you somewhat than please mark it so others can get help of it as well as from this discussion.

Comment: The question was to help with the caml query, to return a value which = the variable. Sadly you have not assisted in my problem. But thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Yay after much trail and error I found a solution:

If looking to search Sharepoint list by variable using CAML & Javascript then the query string below will bring back id (or value if dropdown etc) and field data.  The code in my question hasn't changed except the query string:

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Prod_x0020_Name\"></FieldRef><Value Type=\"Text\">"+ ProdName +"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");
```

Hope this helps others :)